# How to check/find if an item is in a DEQUE

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, artificial-intelligence

In the code above the else-if part gives me error. The meaning of else-if is: ***else if the value of x isn't in the deque then...***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stack>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
deque<char> visited;
char x;

   if (x==target[4][4])
   {
           visited.push_back(x);            
           return (visited);
   }
   else if (!(find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), x)))
   {
       visited.push_back(x);
   }
```

**ERROR**:no operator "!" matches these operands

Comment: What error does it give you? find() returns visited.end() if not found, not NULL btw.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If `std::find` cannot find the specific value, it will return the "end" of the iterator pair.

```
else if (std::find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), x) == visited.end())
{
   // process the case where 'x' _is_not_ found between
   // visited.begin() and visited.end()
```

---

Edit: If you want to know if *x* **is** in the deque, just reverse the condition.

```
else if (std::find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), x) != visited.end())
{
   // process the case where 'x' _is_ found between
   // visited.begin() and visited.end()
```

---

Edit: If you are unfamiliar with the iterator concept in C++, please read [Understanding Iterators in the STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606973/understanding-iterators-in-the-stl).

Comment: @georgemano: It cannot. `.end()` points to the location after the back of the deque.

Answer (score 9):

For those who visited this page to simply know how to check/find elements in dequeue. 
A quick solution is as below:

Use **std::find()** method:

```
numbers.push_back(10);
numbers.push_front(20);
numbers.push_back(30);
numbers.push_front(40);

deque<int>::iterator it = find(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 20);
if(it!=numbers.end())
{
    // Do your stuff. Here I am simply deleting the element
    it = numbers.erase(it); 
    // Note: Always save returned iterator from erase/insert method, otherwise
    // iterator will point to deleted resource, which leads to undefined behaviour.
}
```

Hope this will help somebody. :)