# in c++, iterator, why sometime I use it and sometimes use *it?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

This one uses *it

```
int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin() ; it != myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

This uses it.

```
  for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
```

Comment: Do you know what `->` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symantics of iterator is pointer. So imagine you have a pointer on each element. If you have a pointer `it` to an element of the vector, you can dereference it using `*` operator and get the element. The same is for pointer to the map element, which is a key/value pair. So dereferencing the pointer on a map element, you get `std::pair`. The key can be accessed by `it->first` or `(*it).first`, the value `it->second` or `(*it).second`.

```
for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << '\n';
```

or better use auto type deduction instead of writing iterator type explicitly (if your compiler supports C++11):

```
for (auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << '\n';
```

or even better use a new syntax (since C++11) as it is clearer and shorter:

```
for (const auto& elem: myvector)
  std::cout << ' ' << elem;

for (const auto& elem: mymap)
  std::cout << elem.first << " => " << elem.second << '\n';
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `it->first` is equivalent to `(*it).first`. In either case you're dereferencing the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

They're equivalent. `*it` dereferences the iterator, and `it->` does the same thing.

We could rewrite the second example to be:

```
for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << '\n';
       //        ^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^
```

The `->` operator is just cleaner in my opinion. Some people always use `(*it)` anyway. Purely style preference.

Answer (score 1):

- `it` is a pointer to the **value** (the iterator)
- `*it` is the **value**

read: [understanding-iterators-in-STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606973/understanding-iterators-in-the-stl)