# why should we use pointer for this code?

Tags: c++, iterator

I found following code from tutorial of C++.
In:

```
cout << "value of v = " << *v << endl;
```

you can see that `*v` is used. Can you tell me why should not we use `v` instead of `*v`?

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   // create a vector to store int
   vector<int> vec; 
   int i;


   // access 5 values from the vector
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      cout << "value of vec [" << i << "] = " << vec[i] << endl;
   }

   // use iterator to access the values
   vector<int>::iterator v = vec.begin();
   while( v != vec.end()) {
      cout << "value of v = " << *v << endl;
      v++;
   }
   cin.get();
   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print the iterator, or the thing it points to?

Comment: simply because `v` is an `iterator`, and you need to dereference it to get it's value

Comment: I do not like that sample. Better is `for(vector<int>::iterator v = vec.begin(); v != vec.end(); ++v)` with pre-increment or a C++11 range based loop

Comment: The sample is fine, Dieter.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `v` is

```
vector<int>::iterator v
```

Therefore if you tried to do

```
<< v << endl;
```

you'd be trying to write the `iterator` to the output stream, whereas you want the `int`. Therefore, to dereference an iterator, you use the `*` operator to get at the underlying object contained within the iterator

```
<< *v << endl
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain a bit more about vector<int>::iterator v?

Comment: See if reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606973/understanding-iterators-in-the-stl) helps.

Answer (score 1):

A `vector<int>::iterator` is *essentially* a pointer to an `int`.

More formally, the iterator type overloads the *dereference* operator to return the element to which the iterator is currently referring.

That's why you need to write `<< *v` if you want to abstract the value. (But don't do it if `v` is at `vec.end()` - the behaviour on dereferencing that is undefined).

Comment: `s/abstract/extract/`?